# What strlen(pointer of char) is returning?

Tags: pointers, strlen

I got the following code :

```
char sir[1000], *psir;
cout << "Introduceti sirul de caractere: ";
strcpy(sir ,"merge") ;
int dim;
dim = sizeof(sir);
cout << "Dimensiunea zonei de memorie asociata variabilei masiv sir:"\
    << dim << endl;
dim = strlen(sir);
cout << "Lungimea sirului de caractere introdus:" << dim << endl;

psir = new char[dim + 1];
dim = strlen(psir);
```

When I run this code ,i get 22,on the last statement and I don't see why.
Can someone explain?

Comment: I mean dim=22 ,when the last one runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new char array with New, which is great. But its not initialized, so asking about its contents would yield unexpected answers.

Comment: Thanks mate!I was really confused about what happened.

Comment: 4 minutes to go